# Allow a wallet to call a single contract

Tags: ledger-nano-s, raspberry-pi

I want to build an electronic device. This device can be a raspberry pi with a ledger USB device, or anything else.

This device will need to call an Ethereum smart contract. For example let's suppose i want to measure temperature and to write something on the blockchain if temperature is greater than a threshold.

So i need to embed a wallet inside the device because it will spend GAS/Ether for transactions.

This device will be outdoor and i have to consider it might be stolen.

What i want to do is to protect the wallet in order to only allow calls on a specific smart contract. If someone stole the device and access to private key, i want to be sure he won't be able to spend Ether for anything else.

Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: `i want to be sure he won't be able to spend Ether for anything else` - no, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The device can be outside. Disposable hardware. $5 for RasPi Zero.

Assuming you want to transmit the transaction, there is internet connection.

Use API and make calls to a server you control that keeps the private key.

---

To answer your question... A proxy contract can be implemented to call one specific smart contract. But that's creates egg-chcicken problem, who can call the proxy contract?

EOA (externally owned account) cannot be limited to call one specific contract only.

Comment: Quoting the question: `If someone stole the device and access to private key...`. So this is not a smart contract, and the simple answer is - No, this is not possible.